# gcc - meaning of dangling/loose dash

Tags: gcc

I'm working with micropython and a certain build command is (note the 'dangling' dash at the end):

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -E -I. -I.. -I../stmhal -Ibuild -Icore -Wall -Wpointer-arith -std=gnu99 -nostdlib -mthumb -mtune=cortex-m4 -mcpu=cortex-m4 -msoft-float -mfloat-abi=soft -fsingle-precision-constant -Wdouble-promotion -DF_CPU=96000000 -DUSB_SERIAL -D__MK20DX256__ -Os  -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -DMICROPY_MODULE_FROZEN_STR -
```

The ENTIRE command is:

```
cat {some header files} | {command from above} > genHeader.h
```

Does that dash have a meaning (explicit or implicit)?

Comment: Assuming arm-none-eabi-gcc acts like regular gcc, it is telling gcc to read from stdin (from your pipe) rather than from a file.

Comment: @EdmCoff set that as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming arm-none-eabi-gcc acts like regular gcc, it is telling gcc to read from stdin (from your pipe) rather than from a file.